# iPhone - Not able to vibrate the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone-vibrate

I am using this

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Importing that

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```

Then an error is what I got!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:"_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably haven't added the `AudioToolbox.framework` to your project.

You can do this in the `Build Phases` section of your Target configuration.  Under `Build Phases` select `Link Binary with Libraries`.  Make sure `AudioToolbox.framework` is in the list of frameworks.  If it isn't click the `+` button at the bottom and select `AudioToolbox.framework` from the list.

Comment: Everytime I forgot to do so! Like really "Everytime" I import the AVFoundation and forgot to import the AudioToolbox. Thanks, man.